# Find if a date is included in a copyright

Tags: python, regex

For validation, I need to see if a copyright line contains a 4-digit date. This would be a valid copyright:

```
Copyright 2005, Fox
```

However, this would not:

```
Copyright Fox
```

How could I use regular expressions to check if a string contains a four-digit date?

Comment: What have you tried? Matching four digits is really basic regex stuff that any tutorial should cover already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use...

```
"Copyright @2003, Billy Moon".match(/copyright\W+\d{4}/i)
```

Which means the word `copyright` followed by 1 or more non-word characters (`\W+`) followed by four digits (`\d{4}`) insensitive to case (`i`)

Answer (score 0):

```
m = re.group('[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]', copyright)
try:
    m.group(0)
except AttributeError:
    copyright='Invalid'
else:
    copyright=copyright
```